# Vertx cluster member connection breaks on hazelcast uuid reset

Tags: hazelcast, vert.x, vertx-verticle, vertx-eventbus

I am working on a project that is composed of multiple vertx micro services where each service runs on different containers in Openshift platform. Eventbus is used for communication between services.

Sometime when a request is made via eventbus there is no response and failing with below errors

```
[vert.x-eventloop-thread-2] DEBUG io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.clustered.ConnectionHolder - tx.id=ea60ebe0-1d81-4041-80d5-79cbe1d2a11c Not connected to server
[vert.x-eventloop-thread-2] WARN  io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.clustered.ConnectionHolder - tx.id=97441ebe-8ce9-42b2-996d-35455a5b32f2 Connecting to server 65c9ab20-43f8-4c59-8455-ecca376b71ac failed
```

Whenever this happen I can see the below error in the destination server to which above request was made

```
message=WARNING: [192.168.33.42]:5701 [cdart] [5.0.3] Resetting local member UUID. Previous: 65c9ab20-43f8-4c59-8455-ecca376b71ac, new: 8dd74cdf-e4c4-443f-a38e-3f6c36721795
```

Could this be due to reset event raised by Hazelcast is not handled in Vertx?

Vertx 4.3.5 version is used in this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-hazelcast/issues/164) that will be fixed in the forthcoming 4.4 release.

Comment: Could you please give a tentative release date?

Comment: Most probably within the next 2 weeks